# Deploying a JHipster/MongoDB application to Heroku

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, heroku, jhipster

JHipster offers sub-generators for deploying applications to cloud providers (such as Heroku and Openshift), but not for applications using MongoDB due to the fact that [Mongeez requires admin privileges](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/733) which of course is not possible within a PaaS environment.

However, it should be possible to run JHipster + MongoDB on cloud providers as long as Mongeez is deactivated. I did the following (using Heroku):

- First, I manually exported the MongoDB database that was created by JHipster on my local development machine and imported it on a Mongolab instance.
- In case the used profile is `prod`, Mongeez doesn't get instantiated.
- After some modifications to JHipster's [Heroku subgenerator](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/tree/master/heroku), it was possible to deploy the app to Heroku. The generator now ignores `_HerokuDatabaseConfiguration.java` (which is for JDBC) and in the used Procfile, I changed the profile to `prod` (instead of `prod,heroku`) and removed the parameter `--spring.datasource.heroku-url=$DATABASE_URL`.

It works quite well, but I have problems with injecting the MongoDB connection string. At the moment, the credentials are "hardcoded" into `application-prod.yml`, so it would be necessary to redeploy the whole application in case of a change of the credentials. In another attempt, I added `spring.data.mongodb.uri=$MONGOLAB_URI` to the Procfile, but there wasn't any effect (unless I missed something).

So how could I solve this issue? As I said, the application is running on Heroku without any problems, but it would be nice to derive the connection details from e.g. the MONGOLAB_URI environment variable. In other news, I have a feeling that I don't understand the `cloud` profile (which I do not use at the moment).

Comment: To clarify, you did try putting `--spring.data.mongodb.uri=$MONGOLAB_URI` in your `Procfile`? I would expect that to work as long as you're not also overriding it in the yml file.

Comment: I've done basically the same thing as you, and it's working too. I'd like to have it "automatically working" with JHipster, so if you find a way (mostly to replace Mongeez), don't hesitate to contribute back to the project!

Comment: @codefinger yes, I put it in the procfile. And you are correct, the yml file seems to have a higher priority. But when I remove the "data/mongo"-part from the yml file, I get `Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must not be empty`

Comment: @JulienDubois I will definitely keep an eye on it. I think MongoDB + Cloud Providers are a good combination.

Comment: @JulienDubois I have migrated my project and the generator to mongobee. Feel free to take a look at it in the [PR](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/3479) on github

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Mongeez you can use [**mongobee**](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee/wiki/How-to-use-mongobee) to provide the migration logic for your app.

I've tried it and **it works on heroku**.

This is my default mongobee migration code for jhipster that has the same effect as the mongeez one.

```
package your.package.name.config.dbmigrations;

import com.github.mongobee.changeset.ChangeLog;
import com.github.mongobee.changeset.ChangeSet;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObjectBuilder;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Creates the initial database setup
 */
@ChangeLog(order = "001")
public class InitialSetupMigration {


    private Map<String, String>[] authoritiesUser = new Map[]{new HashMap<>()};

    private Map<String, String>[] authoritiesAdminAndUser = new Map[]{new HashMap<>(), new HashMap<>()};

    {
        authoritiesUser[0].put("_id", "ROLE_USER");

        authoritiesAdminAndUser[0].put("_id", "ROLE_USER");
        authoritiesAdminAndUser[1].put("_id", "ROLE_ADMIN");
    }

    @ChangeSet(order = "01", author = "initiator", id = "01-addAuthorities")
    public void addAuthorities(DB db) {
        DBCollection authorityCollection = db.getCollection("jhi_authority");
        authorityCollection.insert(
            BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                .add("_id", "ROLE_ADMIN")
                .get());
        authorityCollection.insert(
            BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                .add("_id", "ROLE_USER")
                .get());
    }


    @ChangeSet(order = "02", author = "initiator", id = "02-addUsers")
    public void addUsers(DB db) {
        DBCollection usersCollection = db.getCollection("jhi_user");
        usersCollection.createIndex("login");
        usersCollection.createIndex("email");
        usersCollection.insert(BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
            .add("_id", "user-0")
            .add("login", "system")
            .add("password", "$2a$10$mE.qmcV0mFU5NcKh73TZx.z4ueI/.bDWbj0T1BYyqP481kGGarKLG")
            .add("first_name", "")
            .add("last_name", "System")
            .add("email", "system@localhost")
            .add("activated", "true")
            .add("lang_key", "en")
            .add("created_by", "system")
            .add("created_date", new Date())
            .add("authorities", authoritiesAdminAndUser)
            .get()
        );
        usersCollection.insert(BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
            .add("_id", "user-1")
            .add("login", "anonymousUser")
            .add("password", "$2a$10$j8S5d7Sr7.8VTOYNviDPOeWX8KcYILUVJBsYV83Y5NtECayypx9lO")
            .add("first_name", "Anonymous")
            .add("last_name", "User")
            .add("email", "anonymous@localhost")
            .add("activated", "true")
            .add("lang_key", "en")
            .add("created_by", "system")
            .add("created_date", new Date())
            .add("authorities", new Map[]{})
            .get()
        );
        usersCollection.insert(BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
            .add("_id", "user-2")
            .add("login", "admin")
            .add("password", "$2a$10$gSAhZrxMllrbgj/kkK9UceBPpChGWJA7SYIb1Mqo.n5aNLq1/oRrC")
            .add("first_name", "admin")
            .add("last_name", "Administrator")
            .add("email", "admin@localhost")
            .add("activated", "true")
            .add("lang_key", "en")
            .add("created_by", "system")
            .add("created_date", new Date())
            .add("authorities", authoritiesAdminAndUser)
            .get()
        );
        usersCollection.insert(BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
            .add("_id", "user-3")
            .add("login", "user")
            .add("password", "$2a$10$VEjxo0jq2YG9Rbk2HmX9S.k1uZBGYUHdUcid3g/vfiEl7lwWgOH/K")
            .add("first_name", "")
            .add("last_name", "User")
            .add("email", "user@localhost")
            .add("activated", "true")
            .add("lang_key", "en")
            .add("created_by", "system")
            .add("created_date", new Date())
            .add("authorities", authoritiesUser)
            .get()
        );
    }

    @ChangeSet(author = "initiator", id = "03-addSocialUserConnection", order = "03")
    public void addSocialUserConnection(DB db) {
        DBCollection socialUserConnectionCollection = db.getCollection("jhi_social_user_connection");
        socialUserConnectionCollection.createIndex(BasicDBObjectBuilder
                .start("user_id", 1)
                .add("provider_id", 1)
                .add("provider_user_id", 1)
                .get(),
            "user-prov-provusr-idx", true);
    }
}
```

In the `DatabaseConfiguration.java` file remove mongeez and add

```
@Bean
public Mongobee mongobee() {

    log.debug("Configuring Mongobee");

    Mongobee mongobee = new Mongobee(mongo);
    mongobee.setDbName(mongoProperties.getDatabase());
    mongobee.setChangeLogsScanPackage(
        "de.shaere.sharecore.config.dbmigrations"); // package to scan for changesets
    mongobee.setEnabled(true);
    return mongobee;
}
```

And finally update your gradle file removing the mongeez dependency and adding:

```
compile group: 'com.github.mongobee', name: 'mongobee', version: mongobee_version
```

I've also opened a [pull request](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/3479) to update the JHipster generator. Now we wait to see if the guys agree :)