# Deploying a jHipster with MongoDB app to Heroku, with ObjectRocket addon

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, heroku, jhipster

I have created a jHipster application that uses a MongoDB database. I am trying for the last few days to deploy it on Heroku.
I've run the heroku generator as required. "jhipster heroku". I also pushed the code to the heroku branch with "git push heroku master". However, I still have a problem.

Caused by:

> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbFactorySupport]: Factory
> method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The
> connection string is invalid. Connection strings must start with
> either 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv://

I do realize that I have to place the MongoDB connection string, provided by the ObjectRocket addon, somewhere in the .yml files, but I am not sure where. This is not a duplicate of [Deploying a JHipster/MongoDB application to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014405/deploying-a-jhipster-mongodb-application-to-heroku) because that question was asked 5 years ago and since then, Heroku provided a subgenerator for MongoDB apps on Heroku.
Also, should I modify the Profile somehow?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

JHipster should have generated a `application-heroku.yml` under `src/main/resources`. It should contain the spring data property for the mongo db connection (`spring.data.mongodb.uri`). You should replace the value with your object rocket connection string.

Side note, why you have the errors message: JHipster uses only add-ons with a free tier. For mongo db it was mLab's addon. Sadly it has been discontinued. There is an open issue to update JHipster's heroku integration accordingly. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/13424

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it finally. I suspected it due to the application-heroku.yml file. But this was not the only problem for me. The main problem was that I didn;t knew I have to edit the Procfile also. Tip for anyone that lands here. You should check that the Procfile is also edited with the database name.